# NodeJS: HTTPS Server error w/ host key (wrong tag?)

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am receiving an error when the https server starts, something along the lines of:

`Error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag`

I may be completely going about this the wrong way. I need to get an SSL cert from a 3rd party CA. This CA requires that I give them a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) that I have generated.

I generated a CSR using certreq.exe on Windows and provided the CSR to them. They provided the public key cert in response.

Here's where I'm a little confused. The https server has a `key` and `cert` property. As I understand, `cert` is for the public key (from the CA) and `key` is for the private key. Where's this private key??

After some googling, it appears that certreq.exe will create a key pair in the windows cert store when the CSR is generated. I exported the PFX, used openssl to extract the private key, and decrypted the key so that it was in a format that had "--BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY.. etc". The key looks fine to me. It's formatted the same way my previous self-signed certs were formatted which worked fine.

I used this private key for the https `key` property and received that `asn1 wrong tag` error. Am I going about getting the private key the wrong way? Or is the error something else?

Comment: This error is due to invalid certificate format -- either additional or trailing spaces in the certificate or Installing a certificate format other than X.509

Comment: I've verified several times that there are no trailing spaces/etc. So if it is the latter, how can I verify that?

Comment: Is it possible it means the public key is "corrupt"? Not the private key?

Comment: It could be. Also I read somewhere to delete Begin and End line. Try that as well.

Comment: I think I've got it.. the private key is in PKCS1 format and has "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" .. I actually need PKCS8 format with "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" .. going to convert and try

Comment: And it worked! So everything was fine, it was just in the wrong format.